# Can not install xchat on Ubuntu 16.04lts

Tags: 16.04, xchat

When I run
    sudo apt-get install xchat

it builds dependency tree and then error comes
    E: Package 'xchat' has no installation candidate
what should I do?

Comment: the total output was:
**Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package xchat is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'xchat' has no installation candidate**

Comment: Maybe you can look at `hexchat` program. It's based on `xchat 2`.

Comment: So,can't I install xchat?There are few problems in Hexchat.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that package is named `xchat-gnome` ([packages.ubuntu.com](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&searchon=names&keywords=xchat) helps).